# Angular2 application buiild error suddenly with gulp rollup:fesm

Tags: angular, gulp

My angular2 application was working fine until recently. Today i ran `npm run build` and getting lot of errors. Not sure what has happened. I am using visual studio code as IDE.

```
Starting 'rollup:fesm'...
The following options have been renamed — please update your config: entry -> input, format -> output.format
'rxjs/Rx' is imported by build\services\alerts\alert.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'rxjs/Observable' is imported by build\services\alerts\alert.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'rxjs/add/operator/catch' is imported by build\services\alerts\alert.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'rxjs/add/operator/do' is imported by build\services\alerts\alert.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
'rxjs/add/operator/catch' is imported by build\services\counterparties\counterparty.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an exter
nal dependency
'rxjs/add/operator/do' is imported by build\services\counterparties\counterparty.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external
 dependency
'rxjs/Rx' is imported by build\services\abstract-rest.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'rxjs/Observable' is imported by build\services\abstract-rest.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
'rxjs/add/operator/catch' is imported by build\services\abstract-rest.service.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
```

gulpfile.js:

```
/**
 * 5. Run rollup inside the /build folder to generate our Flat ES module and place the
 *    generated file into the /dist folder
 */
gulp.task('rollup:fesm', function () {
  return gulp.src(`${buildFolder}/**/*.js`)
  // transform the files here.
    .pipe(rollup({

      // Bundle's entry point
      // See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API#entry
      entry: `${buildFolder}/index.js`,

      // Allow mixing of hypothetical and actual files. "Actual" files can be files
      // accessed by Rollup or produced by plugins further down the chain.
      // This prevents errors like: 'path/file' does not exist in the hypothetical file system
      // when subdirectories are used in the `src` directory.
      allowRealFiles: true,

      // A list of IDs of modules that should remain external to the bundle
      // See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API#external
      external: [
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/forms',
        '@angular/router',
        'primeng/primeng'
      ],

      // Format of generated bundle
      // See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API#format
      format: 'es'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
});
```

Below is the tsconfig json. Everthing was working fine earlier. I even did npm cache clean.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true    
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ui-core",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "build:watch": "gulp",
    "docs": "npm run docs:build",
    "docs:build": "compodoc -p tsconfig.json -n ui-core -d docs --hideGenerator",
    "docs:serve": "npm run docs:build -- -s",
    "docs:watch": "npm run docs:build -- -s -w",
    "lint": "tslint --type-check --project tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts",
    "test": "tsc && karma start"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "email": "xx@yy.com"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular"
  ],
  "license": "TIM",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "@types/d3": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rollup": "^2.11.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "node-sass-tilde-importer": "^1.0.0",
    "node-watch": "^0.5.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "rollup": "^0.41.6",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "@ngscaffolding/core": "^1.1.10",
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "~4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Also i get the following in the output window of visual studio code:

```
[Info  - 11:50:54] 
Failed to load the ESLint library for the document c:\Projects\Latest_Feb26\ASSURE.OdyssEYGen2\FrontEnd\OdyssEY-UI-Core\gulpfile.js

To use ESLint in this workspace please install eslint using 'npm install eslint' or globally using 'npm install -g eslint'.
You need to reopen the workspace after installing eslint.
```

Can anyone please help me with this error?

Comment: did you do npm i before trying to build again?

Comment: yes, i did npm i. I even took a complete new copy of my code from repo.

Comment: can you share your package.json, i suspect your rxjs lib updated itself and the rxjs/Rx import is not longer valid.